# I cant use any keytool command

Tags: keytool

The command I used is this

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\userName\.android\debug.keystore" -list -v
```

and it gives this error

```
keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\userNa ...
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (keytool:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check JDK is configured properly in system or not
2. If Java is configured properly, check Andriod SDK is installed properly or not
3. If Android SDK is installed, then run below command in Command Prompt,

keytool -list -keystore %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore

This is a debug certificate that we can use in FireBase.

Comment: the jdk and sdk are installed

Comment: but it does show this Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\User1.android\debug.keystore user 1 being my user